# sed to replace all occurrences of a left zero padded number having an embedded minus sign “-“ so that the minus sign is on the Left

Tags: sed

I have a tab delimited input file.  Some numeric field values have a minus sign in the midst of the value such as `000-45.123`.  I need the `-` to be on left side like this instead:  `-00045.123`

So if tab delimited input file contains: (spaces are tabs)

```
ABC 000-45.123 0-765.43 DEF 00-54 XYZ
```

then I want result to be

```
ABC -00045.123 -0765.43 DEF -0054 XYZ
```

All the number values with an embedded “-“ begin with 1 or more zeros and no other characters.

Note: I don't have these options available: sed -r or sed -E

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

Change order from number and minus to minus and number.

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)(-)/\2\1/g' file
```

Output:

```
ABC     -00045.123      -0765.43        DEF     -0054   XYZ
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: As long as the input is as described in the question (All the number values with an embedded “-” begin with 1 or more zeros *and **no other characters**.*), this will work. But, if the input contains “867‑5309”, this will output “‑8675309”. Why not just do `0+` instead of `[0-9]+`?

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
TAB=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/^\(00*\)-/-\1/;s/${TAB}\(00*\)-/$TAB-\1/g"
```

We need to consider the two cases of the first field (`00-` at the start of the line) or the other fields (`00-` following a TAB).

With `sed` implementations supporting `-E` (for extended regular expressions) and shells supporting `$'...'` (both of which are likely to make it into a future version of the POSIX specification), you can simplify it to:

```
sed -E $'s/(^|\t)(0+)-/\1-\2/g'
```

instead.